# VBA for-loop over specific files and confirm date

Tags: excel, vba, date, for-loop

I have three workbooks (Book1,Book2,Book3) all saved as xlsx files. Each day, these workbooks are updated. Assume all workbooks belong to the following directory: C:\Users\abc\Documents\Example which also contains many other files (d,e,f.... etc). I need to check that Book1,Book2,Book3 are updated so that 'Date Modified' = Today's date. If date modified does not equal today's date i need the code to stop running and warn "Incorrect Date". I imagine this task will involve running a for-loop but I am quite new to VBA.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-loops.html) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim arrFileNames As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strExt As String

    arrFileNames = Split("Book1,Book2,Book3", ",")
    strPath = "C:\Users\marios.p\Desktop\test" & "\"
    strExt = ".xlsx"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For i = LBound(arrFileNames) To UBound(arrFileNames)

        Set f = fs.GetFile(strPath & arrFileNames(i) & strExt)

        If f.DateLastModified < Date Then
            MsgBox "Incorrect Date"
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```